# fill na with random numbers in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, random, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark DataFrame.

I'd like to update NA values in *Age* column with a random value in the range 14 to 46.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

Mara's answer is correct if you would like to replace the null values with the same random number, but if you'd like a random value for each age, you should do something coalesce and F.rand() as illustrated below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from random import randint

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 23.0), (3, "B", -23.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))

df = (df
    .withColumn("x4", F.lit(None).cast(IntegerType()))
    .withColumn("x5", F.lit(None).cast(IntegerType()))
    )
    
df.na.fill({'x4':randint(0,100)}).show()
df.withColumn('x5', F.coalesce(F.col('x5'), (F.round(F.rand()*100)))).show()


+---+---+-----+---+----+
| x1| x2|   x3| x4|  x5|
+---+---+-----+---+----+
|  1|  a| 23.0|  9|null|
|  3|  B|-23.0|  9|null|
+---+---+-----+---+----+
+---+---+-----+----+----+
| x1| x2|   x3|  x4|  x5|
+---+---+-----+----+----+
|  1|  a| 23.0|null|44.0|
|  3|  B|-23.0|null| 2.0|
+---+---+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: What if I don't want my random numbers to start at 0 but let's say at 10?

Answer (score 0):

The randint function is what you need: it generates a random integer between two numbers. Apply it in the fillna spark function for the 'age' column.

```
from random import randint
df.fillna(randint(14, 46), 'age').show()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!